# How to apply filter on an array in a collection in firestore

Tags: javascript, ionic3, angular5, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I want to filter out the only content which is book marked by user,
the structure of the data is shared below

[image: snap is attached]

```js
this.contentList = afs.collection < Content > ('Content',
    ref =>
    ref.where('isActive', '==', true)

    .where("BookmarkedBy.UserID", "==", "hvC2WQL5JJG3Hbq1hxJe")
  )
  .snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
    return actions.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Content;
      data.$key = a.payload.doc.id;
      return { ...data
      };
    });
  });
```

I think i'm making mistake here

```
.where("BookmarkedBy.UserID","==" , "hvC2WQL5JJG3Hbq1hxJe")
```

Is there any way I can apply filter on array items inside a collection?
any help in this regards will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @VadimKotov I have updated the tags, kindly if you could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
    title: "My great post",
    categories: [
        "technology",
        "opinion",
        "cats"
    ]
}
```

With the data structure above, there is no way to perform this query.

Consider this alternative data structure, where each category is the key in a map and all values are true:

```
{
    title: "My great post",
    categories: {
        "technology": true,
        "opinion": true,
        "cats": true
    }
}
```

Reference [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays)

Comment: @Aay Que Try This if worked for you kindly accept and upvote